# Ember 3.2.2 not routing request to .NET Core 2.1 JSON web API

Tags: javascript, ember.js, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi

I am new to using Ember and have been following an online video tutorial (see weblink below, though its dated as it uses .NET Core 1.0) that demonstrates how to setup a JSON API back-end with an Ember front-end - I am using Visual Studio Code. I have successfully completed the first video and receive responses from the JSON API back-end. However, I am unable to get the second video working by having Ember send a request to the api-back end for data retrieval. I know this because I am monitoring the calls to the server. So, while I can hit the back-end server and receive a JSON response, the front-end response is HTTP Error 404 - page not found and there is no request to the back-end.

**HTTP Error:**

```
Error: Ember Data Request GET /todo-items returned a 404
Payload (text/html; charset=utf-8)
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Error</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <pre>Cannot GET /todo-items</pre>
    </body>
</html>
```

My best guess is that changes have been made to .NET Core and Ember with respect to routing that are not covered in the videos. Unfortunately, a 404 error is very little to go on and I am unable to find the problem. Does anybody know where the problem is or how I can troubleshoot this?

**Video tutorial:** https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_d53rG2i9pY&index=2&list=PLu4Bq53iqJJAo1RF0TY4Q5qCG7n9AqSZf

**router.js**

```
import EmberRouter from '@ember/routing/router';
import config from './config/environment';

const Router = EmberRouter.extend({
  location: config.locationType,
  rootURL: config.rootURL
});

Router.map(function() {
  this.route('todo-items');
});

export default Router;
```

**environment.js**

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function(environment) {
  let ENV = {
    modulePrefix: 'todo-list-client',
    environment,
    rootURL: '/',
    locationType: 'auto',
    EmberENV: {
      FEATURES: {
        // Here you can enable experimental features on an ember canary build
        // e.g. 'with-controller': true
      },
      EXTEND_PROTOTYPES: {
        // Prevent Ember Data from overriding Date.parse.
        Date: false
      }
    },

    APP: {
      host: 'http://localhost:5000',
      namespace: 'api/v1'
    }
  };

  if (environment === 'development') {
    // ENV.APP.LOG_RESOLVER = true;
    // ENV.APP.LOG_ACTIVE_GENERATION = true;
    // ENV.APP.LOG_TRANSITIONS = true;
    // ENV.APP.LOG_TRANSITIONS_INTERNAL = true;
    // ENV.APP.LOG_VIEW_LOOKUPS = true;
  }

  if (environment === 'test') {
    // Testem prefers this...
    ENV.locationType = 'none';

    // keep test console output quieter
    ENV.APP.LOG_ACTIVE_GENERATION = false;
    ENV.APP.LOG_VIEW_LOOKUPS = false;

    ENV.APP.rootElement = '#ember-testing';
    ENV.APP.autoboot = false;
  }

  if (environment === 'production') {
    // here you can enable a production-specific feature
  }

  return ENV;
};
```

**application.js**

```
import DS from 'ember-data';
import ENV from './config/environment';

export default DS.JSONAPIAdapter.extend({
    namespace: ENV.APP.namespace,
    host: ENV.APP.host
})
```

**todo-items.js**

```
import Route from '@ember/routing/route';

export default Route.extend({
    model(){
        return this.store.findAll('todo-item');
    }
});
```

**Model Files:**

**todo-item.js**

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

const { attr, belongsTo} = DS;

export default DS.Model.extend({
    description: attr('string'),
    owner: belongsTo('person')
});
```

**person.js**

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

const { attr, hasMany} = DS;

export default DS.Model.extend({
    firstName: attr('string'),
    lastName: attr('string'),
    todoItems: hasMany('todo-item')
});
```

**UPDATE 1:**

API server is running on port 5000 while Ember is running on 4200.

- API URL call: http://localhost:5000/api/v1/people
- Ember URL call: http://localhost:4200/todo-items

**Update 2**

Server messages:

- API: Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
- Ember: Serving on http://localhost:4200/

Comment: Could you please tell on which port is your server running as well as the network call that is being made to the server from the developer tools in Chrome? Please check if you can hit the same URL from Postman. Please note that the findAll function makes its own request depending on the pluralization, the APIAdapter, etc. being used.

Comment: @AnkitSharma I have updated my OP (scroll to the bottom of the OP). I tried going to todo-item (singular) but that gave me a `UnrecognizedURLError: /todo-item`

Comment: Pluralization depends on what settings have you applied in your adapter. Could you pls check the URL that Ember is hitting for which the server is responding with 404. This can be checked using the network tab in developer tools

Comment: @AnkitSharma I am not getting any data in Postman - this is a separate issue that I am having. I raised separate SO post here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51229094/postman-not-working-on-ember-with-back-end-json-api In the mean time, is there anything I can use in the browser debug tools?

Comment: Not getting data and 404 are two separate issues. Atleast Ember should be able to hit the proper API whether or not it is able to get the required data. Hence, just verify the URL that is being hit by Ember app is same as what you are using in Postman. Not getting the data in Postman could then be debugged at the server side. I hope you know how to check the URL in the dev tools, do you?

Comment: @AnkitSharma I am not sure what to say. I have provided a second update with the server messages. I assume that the combination of server messages, code, and URL links either you or someone else can verify whether or not it is setup correctly.

Comment: I am sorry to say, but the information is not enough for us to help you. I am sure Ember is not hitting the correct URL (endpoint), that's why you are not getting the correct response. You may explore the following video https://egghead.io/lessons/tools-analyze-http-requests-and-responses-with-chrome-devtools . Pls check somewhere around 1:50 where it shows the URL that is being hit.

Comment: @AnkitSharma Yes, the Request URL that is being hit is http://localhost:4200/todo-items and I am receiving a 404 error.

Comment: Did you check that in the dev tools. I dont think so you checked the right URL, because you mentioned your server is running on 5000 and you had already configured host in your application.js adapter and hence the URL must be something like https://localhost:5000.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174613/discussion-between-j-weezy-and-ankit-sharma).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. I needed to setup CORS.

Answer (score 1):

Do you run ember serve with the proxy parameter pointing to your backend?

Try to run this in your terminal:

`ember s -pr=http://localhost:5000`

then your requests should go to the right endpoint.

Comment: I was working with Ankit on this last night via chat and he mentioned over-riding the Ember route to force it to the back end via the model() function. I did not try what you have mentioned, but I will do so this evening and advise of the result.

Comment: Since I am running two separate servers (i.e., Ember front-end and JSON web API back-end), will I always need to have the proxy setup? Also, is this needed for Postman to help troubleshoot issues? see the following post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51229094/postman-not-working-on-ember-with-back-end-json-api?noredirect=1#comment89470964_51229094

Comment: I tried using the proxy but that did not work. I do know that application.js being in the wrong folder. However, the route localhost:4200/todo-items still returns 404. Any idea how to diagnose whether it is coming from Ember or the back-end JSON web API?