# Postman not working on Ember with back-end JSON API

Tags: javascript, ember.js, asp.net-core, postman

I am new to Ember and have posted a similar post regarding troubleshooting of a simple Ember front-end with JSON API web back-end (see below). My problem here is that I am unable to get Postman to display any data in the DevTools console - its blank. I can use Postman to submit requests and see the response in the body, that is all.

I have tried various permutations of using the application while going so far as to uninstall and re-install. But, nothing is working. Is anyone aware of the steps necessary to use Postman to troubleshoot problems?

[Ember 3.2.2 not routing request to .NET Core 2.1 JSON web API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51228614/ember-3-2-2-not-routing-request-to-net-core-2-1-json-web-api)

Comment: I don't get how ember and postman should play together at all. Postman is used to fire HTTP requests and ember is for developing single page applications and not backends. Is this about [ember-fastboot](http://ember-fastboot.com/)?

Comment: If you go to the weblink that I provided in the OP and see the video tutorial from that posting, then you will see the author of the video is using Postman to validate the work that he has done. The original OP is a problem with the link between the front-end and back-end, so I guess it makes sense that Postman would show nothing until that link is fixed. Though, the lack of any info is a bit confusing.

Comment: The video is 20 minutes long. Could you please point me to the actual point in time?

Comment: Its near the end, once everything is setup, he tests it. It is at approximately the 17:50 mark.

Comment: The video is showing the network tab of browser's developers tools at that point of time. That has nothing to do with postman.

Comment: @jelhan OK, I understand now. Thank you for pointing that out. Again, I am new to front-end frameworks specifically and JS broadly. If you want, you can post the answer and I will mark it answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As figured out in comments you were messing up [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) with [developer tools of browser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools).

While Postman is great to debug and test REST APIs, it can't be used to inspect single page applications (SPA) running in browser window. Postman is it's own application and does not interfere with your ember.js web application which is running another task.

To inspect a single page application (or other websites) the developer tools which are provided by all major browsers are very helpfull. These ones are shown in the video you have mentioned in comments. They have a network tab listing all requests fired. [Here](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network-performance/reference) you find a detailed description of Google Chrome's network tab in developer tools. The other browsers share most of the features.

So to put it together: To investigate what network requests are fired by your single page application (e.g. ember.js) use the network tab of browser's developer tools. If you need to investigate your API behavior more in detail (e.g. to see why a network request of your SPA fails), Postman is a great tool to do this.